# Regression on grouped, long-format data

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have a long-format dataframe that, in abstract form, is like this:

```
 date       group    X     Y
2020-01-01    A     10.1  18.2
2020-01-01    B     19.3  18.2
2020-01-02    A     11.9  16.8
2020-01-02    B      6.3  16.8
2020-01-03    A     27.2   9.4
2020-01-03    B     12.7   9.4
```

Here the observations are by `date`, with one outcome `Y` value per observation, and some number of predictor values `X` based on `group` for each date.

I want to model the outcome (using `lm` or similar) as a function of the predictor values for each group for each date. The obvious way to do this is to widen the data using `pivot_wider`:

```
 date       X_A    X_B     Y
2020-01-01  10.1   19.3   18.2
2020-01-02  11.9    6.3   16.8
2020-01-03  27.2   12.7    9.4
```

And then specify the model to include the predictor-by-group columns:
`Y ~ X_A + X_B`

However, this is obviously a toy example, and the real data have far more `group` columns, with more than two levels, so the number of combinations of `X...` columns gets big real fast, which makes model specification very tedious and messy.

My question is, is there an easy way to get the equivalent model specification using the data in the longer format, specifying the `group` column(s) so the model knows what to separate `X` by (or alternatively specifying the `date` column so the model knows to group the outcomes & predictors accordingly)?

(Note that I'm less concerned about interpretability of the coefficients here, as long as the actual model fit and predictions are the same, I don't care about exactly which coefficient means what.)

I originally thought specifying `Y ~ X * group` would be equivalent but on further thought I don't think it is - doing that captures the different relationship between the group `A` values of `X` vs. the group `B` values of `X` with the outcome, but separately, where the exact values of `Y` happen to be the same - it completely misses the fact that values of `X_A` and `X_B` are coming from the same *observation* (with, consequently, the same outcome value). Which, I think, is incorrect - if I'm overthinking and it actually *is* correct to just use an interaction effect like that, would love to hear why.

Comment: You might want to use linear mixed-effect model by adding random effects.

Comment: @LiangZhang could you elaborate?

Comment: do you really have to use `lm`? Algorithms such as `lgbm` or `xgboost` will treat groups as you intend to, without pivoting or anything. You could also expect better accuracy.

Comment: @volkang I'm actually currently using `brm` but am open to alternatives; that said there is something of a premium on simplicity as linear models would be more familiar to the intended audiences

Comment: I would give `lgbm` a chance. Otherwise, training separate model for each `group` by looping over, saving each model as `dict` or a `list`, and making predictions based on the `group` value could be an option, bur not an elegant one.

Comment: Wouldn't training separate models for each `group` run into exactly the same problem as using the interaction effect `Y ~ X * group` with the long format data? Namely, having each group's subset of `X` values fitted to `Y` separately, with no accounting for the link between each date's `X` values

Answer (score 1):

Edit: the original answer was not correct by misunderstanding. The column `group` stores the names for features. Models need features to be on columns with a wider format, so the pivoting is required at length. But formula could be built by `as.formula()` from a string.

---

Skip the following:

I do think this is related to random effects. For example, you could try {lme4} package (I added a random effect term `(1|date)` in the formula, in which accounting for what you expect of the correlation of group A and B for the same date):

```r
library(lme4)
#> 载入需要的程辑包：Matrix
dat <- readr::read_table("
 date       group    X     Y
2020-01-01    A     10.1  18.2
2020-01-01    B     19.3  18.2
2020-01-02    A     11.9  16.8
2020-01-02    B      6.3  16.8
2020-01-03    A     27.2   9.4
2020-01-03    B     12.7   9.4
")
fit <- lmer(Y ~ X * group + (1 | date), dat)
#> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
summary(fit)
#> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#> Formula: Y ~ X * group + (1 | date)
#>    Data: dat
#> 
#> REML criterion at convergence: 23.7
#> 
#> Scaled residuals: 
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -1.15302 -0.04046  0.02795  0.43824  0.58538 
#> 
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#>  date     (Intercept)  0.00    0.000   
#>  Residual             21.87    4.677   
#> Number of obs: 6, groups:  date, 3
#> 
#> Fixed effects:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value
#> (Intercept)  23.0418     6.3722   3.616
#> X            -0.5025     0.3519  -1.428
#> groupB       -9.6981     9.4911  -1.022
#> X:groupB      0.6166     0.6186   0.997
#> 
#> Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#>          (Intr) X      groupB
#> X        -0.906              
#> groupB   -0.671  0.608       
#> X:groupB  0.515 -0.569 -0.909
#> optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
#> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>~

Comment: Yes, they are different but they are correlated.

Comment: So am I understanding right that you're using a random effect for date? to capture the fact that different groups' values on the same date are related to the same outcome for that date?

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch this. Then this might not be proper. Then I think this might not be done without pivoting.

Comment: Were you thinking it was different outcome values for each group for each date?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But then, mixed models not help.